# unicode regex pattern not working

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I am trying to match some unicode charaters sequence:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]{2,}");
    String text = "\\n     \\u05db\\u05d3\\u05d5\\u05e8\\u05d2\\u05dc\\n    <\\/span>\\n<br style=\\";
    Matcher match = pattern.matcher(text);
```

but doing so gives this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 4
  \u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]+
      ^
```

how can I use still use regex with some regex chars (like "[") to match unicode?

EDIT:
I'm trying to parse some text. The text somewhere has a sequence of Unicode characters, which I know their code range.

Edit2:
I am now using ranges instead : `[\\u05d0-\\u05ea]{2,}` but still can't match the text above

Edit3:
ok, now it's working, the problem was I used **two** backslashes instead of **one**, both in the regex and text.
The solution for this is, assuming I know there will be two chars or more:

```
[\u05d0-\u05ea]{2,}
```

Comment: You can't use the range operators `[]` to split up a character literal `\uXXXX`; the character literal has to be a single unit, inside or outside. What is it you're trying to do here, compress your definition of the Unicode characters? Why won't `[\\u05d0-\\u0eff]` work?

Comment: I didn't understand your use of double backslashes in the string to match.

Comment: because otherwise it won't compile

Comment: In your example what part should be matched with your regex? Can you include some ouptut example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what causing the exception:

```
\\u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]}{2,}
  ^^^^
```

The java regular expression parser thinks you are trying to match a Unicode code point using the escape sequence `\uNNNN` so it is giving an exception, because `\u` requires four hexadecimal digits after it and there is only two of them, namely `05` so you need to change it to `\\u0005` if that is what you actually want.

On the other hand, if you want to match `\\u` in the target string, then you need to *quad* escape each backslash `\` like this `\\\\` so to match `\\u` you need `\\\\\\\\u`.

```
\\\\\\\\u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]}{2,}
```

Finally, if you want to match those Unicode code points literally in your target string then you need to modify our last expression a bit like this:

```
(?:\\\\\\\\u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]){2,}
```

**Edit:** Since there is only one backslash in your target string then your regular expression should be:

```
(?:\\\\u05[dDeE][0-9a-fA-F]){2,}
```

This will match `\u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc` in your string

```
<\/span><\/span><span dir=\"rtl\">\n \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc\n <\/span>\n<br style=\"clear : both; font-size : 1px;\">\n<\/div>"}, 200, null, null);
```

**Edit 2:** If you want to match literal `\u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc` then you can't use a range.

On the other hand, if you want to match Unicode code points between `05d0` and `05df` then you can use:

```
(?:[\\u05d0\\u05df]){2,}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant; I think he was trying for shell-style expansion of the Unicode literals.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry I though he was trying to match a Unicode code point. I think I have found the real problem.

Comment: No, there are code-point character literals in `text`, so I do think he's trying that. I think he's just confused about how character ranges work; he seems to think that the code-point hex digits are case-sensitive.

Comment: I wanna match this: `<\/span><\/span><span dir=\"rtl\">\n     \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc\n    <\/span>\n<br style=\"clear : both; font-size : 1px;\">\n<\/div>"}, 200, null, null);` I used double backslashes in my code just to make the text compile, the text is fully correct with 1 backslash

Comment: @user2719361 Please edit your question to show this information, and check my edited answer.

Comment: and if I wanna use ranges instead?

Comment: what does that mean: "(?:"

Comment: @user2719361 This is a non-capturing group. If you used `()` only then whatever the expression between them captures will be saved by the regex engine for later use, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is great resource for learning.

Comment: another question: now this is the text: `.callback(', {"translatedText":"<div class=\"definition\" align=\"right\" dir=\"rtl\">\n<span class=\"BAB_CPPOSStyle\"><span dir=\"rtl\">(\u05e9\"\u05e2)<\/span><\/span><span dir=\"rtl\">\n     \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc\n    <\/span>\n<br style=\"clear : both; font-size : 1px;\">\n<\/div>"}, 200, null, null);` what is the regex to match the unicode chars? the limit for the unicode range is \u05d0-\u05ea

Comment: @user2719361 Just substitute the range in the last expression I gave you. It looks like you are trying to parse HTML with regular expression, don't do that and instead use an XML or HTML parser, usually called a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. If your goal is to simplify matching a range of Unicode characters, then you need to realize that the hex digits are completely case insensitive, and so your `a-fA-F` is redundant, even if you could split character literals. Try this to match all Unicode characters in the range:

```
[\\u05d0-\\u0eff]
```

Comment: ok, unicode is case insensitive I get that. but using this also doesn't match the text (in the question): [\\u05d0-\\u0eff]+

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have unnecessary **`\\`** in your input string. Following works by replacing your specified unicode character range in regex:

```
String text = "\n  \u05db\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8\u05d2\u05dc\n    </span>\n<br style=\\";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[\u05d0-\u05ea]{2,}", "@@@"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  @@@
    </span>
```

Note that in our input text you had `\\n` and `\\u05db` etc that I have fixed.

Comment: My answer was not regarding your inout only, I provided you right syntax for matching unicode character range as well.